# When does RDOMail.Recipients.ResolveAll() gives back false?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

When I add a valid smtp address to my RDOMail object and then trigger the ResolveAll procedure, in some cases the result is false.
How can this be, what is ResolveAll doing exactly.
I thought it does some kind of mapping the "alias" to a valid smtp address, but it seems not.

Answer (score 0):

ResolveAll does the same thing as hitting Ctrl+K in Outlook after you type the recipient names in the To/CC/BCC edit boxes.

If ResolveAll returns false, that means that either the names cannot be resolved at all (the yare not in the address book) or that there are ambiguous entries.

Comment: Just for my understanding. We add a "resolved" smtp address to the mail. Could it it lead to a false, if the smtp address is set in two different address book entries?

Comment: No, SMTP address will always be resolved - if it is not found in any of the address book containers, Outlook/MAPI will at least resolve it to a one-off entry.

Comment: In some cases it leads to false. Do I have to trigger ResolveAll(), when I only use SMTP addresses?

Comment: Until you call Resolve or ResolveAll, the recipient will remain unresolved. Providing an SMTP address is not any different from providing a name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when a fax number is added to the contact in the address book. It seems that the fax number is handled as second address book entry.

[image]

Is there any other way to solve the problem, instead deleting the fax entry?